# How to prevent the rounded woocommerce order's total change back to non-rounding figure after the order is updated

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, rounding

I want to make the total price of an order to be rounded to 0.05, so I added some code in functions.php:

```
function custom_calculated_total( $total ) {
return round( $total * 2, 1) / 2;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'custom_calculated_total' );
```

It works well in cart and checkout that show the total as rounded figure.

However, at the backend to manage customers' order, whenever the admin clicked the update button or the arrow above the update button in an order, the total changed back to the non-rounded figure.

[You can view the update button and the arrow button here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2qXr.png)

Therefore whenever we are going to print an invoice which will caused the update of order, the total changed back to the non-rounded figure in the order and invoice.

I tried others similar coding but the result remains the same.
What should I do to prevent the order total to change back to the non-rounded figure after I update the order?

Answer (score 0):

You can round the very specific output of that table like so:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'round_my_total', 99, 1);
    function round_my_total($value ){
       return round( WC()->cart->get_total(false), 1);
    }
```

**EDIT**
In order to change every place the "get_total()"  is used, you can use the following filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_total', 'round_get_total', 99, 1);
function round_get_total($value ){
    $value = str_replace(get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(), '', strip_tags($value));
    return (round($value * 1, 1));
}
```

Comment: Hi Shir Gans, thank you for your reply! I tried the code you provide, it did rounded the total to 1 decimal point at cart and checkout, but in the order and invoice it still maintains the original total...

Comment: I added a case for that too.

Comment: It still work in cart and checkout only, but after customer checkout, the figure changed back to non-rounding, and the invoice remain non-rounding figure. I made the function to round to 0.05. You can view at https://imgur.com/a/LTw3GFw and https://imgur.com/a/Qh6em2H

Answer (score 0):

Another way, not sure you checked it before, is using WooCommerce built-in option. (I haven't tested it on invoices etc.)

[image]

Comment: Ya, I did think of this settings, but I wish to have 2 decimal with rounding of 0.05, so it couldn't fully satisfy my requirement